# Why does calling a method on a pointer to an object have different behaviour from calling the method on the object itself?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have some code where I have a pointer to an object. I call a method on that pointer but the behaviour of the method is wrong in this case. I tried calling a method on the object itself and this actually gives the desired behaviour of the method.

Why does this cause different behaviour?

Also is there a way of assigning an object to a new variable without using pointers because I want the behaviour for the method called on the object itself?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Hopefully a sufficient example:

In a Robot class:

```
std::vector<ProjectOne::R_ID> Robot::positions;
int Robot::ID = -1;

Robot::Robot(double x, double y)
{
    ++ID;
    robot_ID = ID;
    initialX = x;
    initialY = y;
    // Placeholder. Doesn't actually get used properly atm.
    fWidth = 0.35;
    px = x;
    py = y;

    ProjectOne::R_ID msg;   
    msg.R_ID = robot_ID;
    msg.x = x;
    msg.y = y;
    positions.push_back(msg);

    string robotOdom = "robot_" + int2str(robot_ID) + "/odom";
    string robotVel = "robot_" + int2str(robot_ID) + "/cmd_vel";

    RobotOdometry_sub = n.subscribe<nav_msgs::Odometry>(robotOdom,1000,&Robot::ReceiveOdometry,this);
    RobotVelocity_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>(robotVel,1000);
    ros::spinOnce();
}

void Robot::ReceiveOdometry(nav_msgs::Odometry msg)
{
    //This is the call back function to process odometry messages coming from Stage.    
    px = initialX + msg.pose.pose.position.x;
    py = initialY + msg.pose.pose.position.y;
    ptheta = angles::normalize_angle_positive(asin(msg.pose.pose.orientation.z) * 2);
}

int Robot::selectLeader()
{
    int leader_ID = robot_ID;
    double lowestDistance = 9999999999.9;
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<positions.size();i++)
    {
        double distance = calculateDistance(positions[i].x, positions[i].y, 0.0, 0.0);            
        if (distance < lowestDistance && distance != 0.0)
        {
            leader_ID = positions[i].R_ID;
            lowestDistance = distance;
        }
    }
    ROS_INFO("leader is: %d", leader_ID);
    return leader_ID;
}

double Robot::calculateDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double deltax = x2 - x1;
    double deltay = y2 - y1;
    double distanceBetween2 = pow(deltax, 2) + pow(deltay, 2);
    double distanceBetween = sqrt(distanceBetween2);
    return distanceBetween;
}

double Robot::calculateHeadingChange(double x, double y)
{
    double deltax = x - px;
    double deltay = y - py;
    double angleBetween = atan2(deltay, deltax);
    double headingChange = angleBetween - ptheta;
    return headingChange;
}

void Robot::align(double x, double y)
{
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    double headingChange = calculateHeadingChange(x, y);
    double angularv = headingChange / 5;
    double heading = ptheta + headingChange;

    while (heading > 2 * M_PI)
    {
        heading -= 2 * M_PI;
    }
    while (heading < 0)
    {
        heading += 2 * M_PI;
    }
    geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
    msg.linear.x = 0;
    msg.angular.z = angularv;
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        RobotVelocity_pub.publish(msg);
    ros::spinOnce();
    ROS_INFO("Heading Change %f pthea is %f %f %f", headingChange, ptheta, px, py);
    loop_rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

And this is the code that calls the method:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "robotNode");

    Robot r1(5,10);
    Robot r2(15,20);
    Robot r3(10,30);
    Robot r4(25,16);
    Robot r5(5,28);
    Robot r6(10,10);

    Robot Group[6] = {r1, r2, r3, r4 ,r5, r6};
    std::vector<Robot> Herd;
    int leaderID = r1.selectLeader();

    Robot * leader;

    for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        if (Group[i].robot_ID  == leaderID) {
            leader = &Group[i];
        } else {
            Herd.push_back(Group[i]);
        }
    }

    (*leader).align(0.0, 0.0); //Problem area
}
```

Comment: show us some code please

Comment: This doesn't make alot of sense without an example

Comment: I'm guessing you've run into undefined behaviour somehow. Without seeing a complete *minimal* example that reproduces your problem it's not possible to do more than speculate.

Comment: An example would require my entire code spread across two files because it's a bit complicated... Is there no general answer without it?

Comment: @Jigglypuff: my code does not work. Why ?

Comment: Just rewrite a minimal example of how your classes are declared, instantiated and called.

Comment: you can simplify the call of the method and where dfo you found an error in the code you write...

Comment: A general answer would be something like: It doesn't matter if you call a method through object pointer using `->` operator, or directly on the object through `.` operator. You are doing something wrong if this is not the case for you.

Comment: Maybe it's polymorphism involved.

Comment: I've put in an example now. Hopefully it's enough. This is for a roscpp project

Comment: Are you sure `leader` gets set at least once? Also, you should initialize it to NULL.

Comment: My wild guess is that leader was not found and you are invoking function on initialized pointer (which is undefined behavior). But anyway "not works" or "problem area" is far insufficient description. What happens? What have you expected to happen?

Comment: If you don't use pointers, you're *not* going to use "the object itself", but a copy of it. If you're coming from Java, you must unlearn much of what you have learned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your array (`Group`) and vector (`Herd`) both contain copies of the automatic objects (`r1` and friends); so anything you do to those will not affect the originals.

You probably want to work with pointers instead:

```
Robot * Group[6] = {&r1, &r2, &r3, &r4, &r5, &r6};
std::vector<Robot*> Herd;
```

In general, you need to be careful not to dereference these pointers after the objects are destroyed; in this case you're fine, since the lifetimes of the array and vector are contained within those of the objects.

It might make sense to make the `Robot` class uncopyable, to prevent this kind of mistake.
In C++11, you do this by deleting the copy constructor and copy assignment:

```
Robot(Robot const &) = delete;
void operator=(Robot const &) = delete;
```

In older language versions, declare them private, with no implementation; or (better still) derive from a base class that does that.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed every problem in my program. Sorry about how vague the original question was, I didn't know what the real problem was.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
Robot Group[6] = {r1, r2, r3, r4 ,r5, r6};
int leaderID = r1.selectLeader();
```

The group contains copies of the items. You didn't show us the `Robot` copy constructor, but I assume it assigns a unique ID to the newly constructed `Robot`. If so, none of the elements in the group will have an ID equal to your `leaderID`, and thus your `leader` pointer is never set.

One solution is to make your `Group` an array of `Robot*` pointers rather than an array of `Robot` objects. A similar problem occurs with your `Herd` of robots.